# Show that not every subset of F+ of an ordered field has a least element.

Tags: group-theory

Problem:

Let $F$ be an ordered field. Show that there is a non-empty subset $S$ of $F^+$ that has no least element.

Attempt at a solution:

Suppose that $S=F^+$ and $k$ is the least element. Since $F^+$ is a field, every $n$ has a multiplicative inverse $\frac{1}{n}$. If $k < n$, then, then $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{k}$. We know that if $n, k \in F^+$ and $k<n$, $\frac{1}{n} < k$, so $\frac{1}{n} \in F^+$ is less than $k$, which violates our definition of $k$ as the least element. Therefore, $F^+$ must not have a least element.

(The problem with the above proof is the statement: We know that if $n, k \in F^+$ and $k<n$, $\frac{1}{n} < k$ which is true intuitively, but I don't know how to prove it.)

Comment: Think about the $\dfrac{1}{n}$....

Answer (score 3):

HINT: If $F$ is an ordered field, its characteristic is $0$, so it contains a copy of the positive integers, all of which are in $F^+$. And every non-zero element of $F$ has a multiplicative inverse ...

Comment: Dang, you snagged the LHF as I was typing...

Comment: Careful:  there could be positive things smaller than all $1/n$.  For example, if $F = \mathbb R((x))$ is the field of formal Laurent series over $\mathbb R$, ordered by their size for sufficiently small $x > 0$, then $x$ is a positive element smaller than all $1/n$.  To get something smaller, you'd need to look at (e.g.) $x/2$.

Comment: @Ravi: Doesn’t matter: $\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ has no least element.

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  I was too engrossed in assuming $S = F^+$.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're trying to prove that **not every** subset of $F^+$ contains a least element, it suffices to find **one** example of a subset of $F^+$ without a least element. You get to choose what set to use as an example -- you're not expected to show it for an *arbitrary* $S$ (which is a good thing because *some* possible $S$ do have least elements, such as $S=\{1\}$).

How about letting $S$ be $F^+$ itself?